# Moment.js: Determine whether or not 24 hours has passed or not

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, node-modules

Pretty straightforward, but basically i need to find a check for whether or not 24 hours has passed since a user provided a particular command. (rate-limiting 1 Use / Day) When they use the command, the current time is saved and stored, so that is no problem, but the current system only works on date, checking whether or not `lastDaily`'s date section is less than the current date. this leads to a situation where the command resets at midnight.

I want to make it so that if a user runs the daily command at `2:25PM` on `9/12/2019` they won't be able to use it until that same time (or next minute) the next day.

## Code

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const moment = require("moment");
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { m } = require("../../botconfig.json");

module.exports = {
  config: {
    // Command Config: Hidden for space's sake.
  },

  run: async (bot, message, args) => {
    let userData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("db/userdata.json", "utf8"));

    let sender = message.author;

    // Initialise missing data if needed
    if (!userData[sender.id]) { // if there is no userdata,
      userData[sender.id] = {}; // Create it as an empty object
    }
    if (!userData[sender.id].money) {
      userData[sender.id].money = 1000;
    }
    if (!userData[sender.id].lastDaily) {
      userData[sender.id].lastDaily = "";
    }

    // Save Changes to File
    fs.writeFile("db/userdata.json", JSON.stringify(userData), err => {
      if (err) console.error(err);
    });

    var cancollect = false;
    let ld = userData[sender.id].lastDaily;

    if (ld != moment().format("L")) { // MM/DD/YY
      userData[sender.id].lastDaily = moment().format("L");
      userData[sender.id].money += 500;
      // Send Success Embed
    } else {
      // Send Failure Embed
    }
    // Save Changes Again
    fs.writeFile("db/userdata.json", JSON.stringify(userData), err => {
      if (err) console.error(err);
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: You need to compare the moment saved - the current time when checking <= 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer following example to solve your problem.

```
        let lastExecutionTime = Moment().utc().format(); //your last execution time
        let nextDay = Moment(lastExecutionTime).add(1,'day').utc().format(); // calculate 24 hours next to last access
        let currentTime = Moment().utc().format(); //current time
        let canExecuteNow = Moment(currentTime).isSameOrAfter(nextDay);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are storing the date in the format of `MM/DD/YY`, you cannot check for the time difference. So, inorder to get the time difference, if you can store it in the format of something like `"2019-12-10T10:53:53+05:30"` which you can get by `moment().format()` for current timestamp.

And you can do something like this

```
lastDate = moment().format()
> "2019-12-09T10:53:53+05:30"

nextDay = moment(lastDate).add(1, 'days').format()
> "2019-12-10T10:53:53+05:30"
```

Once you get timestamp in above format, you need to convert the date into unix format

```
lastDate = moment(lastDate).valueOf()
> 1575869033000

nextDay = moment(nextDay).valueOf()
> 1575955433000
```

Now, you can get the difference in time by doing this

```
result = moment(nextDay-lastDate).valueOf()
> 86400000 // which is =24hrs
```

Hope this helps :)